# How to find the value closest to 0 in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

'I have this:

```
Dim ListOfhold As New List(Of Integer)

Dim hold1 as integer = a1 - b1
Dim hold2 as integer = a1 - b2
Dim hold3 as integer = a1 - b3
Dim hold4 as integer = a1 - b4
Dim hold5 as integer = a1 - b5
```

'For example the value of hold1 to hold5 are:

```
16
22
-10
5
42

ListOfhold.add(hold1)
ListOfhold.add(hold2)
ListOfhold.add(hold3)
ListOfhold.add(hold4)
ListOfhold.add(hold5)
```

'I can sort it using `ListOfhold.sort()`

'But I don't know which one of these value is closest to `0` (positives only)

'Can you help this noobie?

Comment: `Dim smallestPositive = hList.Where(Function(q) q > 0).OrderBy(Function(j) j).First()`   Please read [ASk] and take the [tour].  Nine times in ten a question like this which shows no effort will get DVs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**VB Version**
`Dim result = ListOfhold.Where(Function(x) x > 0).Sort()`

**C# Version**
`var result = ListOfhold.Where(x => x > 0 ).Sort();`

You can use the `Where` extension method to filter all the numbers in list which are less than zero, and then apply the `Sort` function.

Comment: The question is tagged with VB.Net, so it would be a good idea to translate the C# code to VB.Net

Comment: Yeah, i converted the code but it seems i pasted the C# code.